# Парсинг с авторизацией ссылок форума selenium python

Tags: php, selenium

Форум аналогичный 4pda, с авторизацией.

Мне нужно проверить статус онлайн пользователей, который отображается на сайте как `<span>`. Общий список пользователей не доступен, поэтому единственный способ - перебирать ссылки, добавляя к ним +1 в конце.

Например: https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showuser=3262727226.

Я пытался реализовать это с помощью requests, прошел аутентификацию (без нее форум не отображается). Цикл прохода по ссылкам был успешен, но при попытках парсинга всей страницы я снова попадал на страницу авторизации или получал 404 ошибку.

Как можно решить эту проблему с учетом авторизации? Я в тупике. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.